# problem with loading local image in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having trouble showing an image using `div` in react js. the path is correct because I can display it using an `img` tag.

**I can't use the `import` method because the filename is going to be taken from a database table.**

this is my code: ([Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-frost-jd1f9c?file=/src/components/Test.js:0-623))

**App.js**

```
import "./styles.css";
import Test from "./components/Test";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <Test />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**./components/Test.js**

```
import img1 from "../assets/images/sandwich.jpg";

const Test = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>This uses the img tag</p>
      <img
        src={img1}
        style={{ width: "100px", height: "100px" }}
        alt="an img tag"
      />
      <p>And this uses a div with backgroundImage</p>
      <div
        style={{
          backgroundImage: `url("../assets/images/sandwich.jpg")`,
          backgroundSize: "cover",
          backgroundPosition: "center",
          width: "200px",
          height: "200px",
          border: "1px solid black"
        }}
      ></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Test;
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for giving us a sandbox to test. Was really helpful.

INSTEAD OF WRITING YOUR CODE LIKE THIS:

```
import img1 from "../assets/images/sandwich.jpg";

const Test = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>This uses the img tag</p>
      <img
        src={img1}
        style={{ width: "100px", height: "100px" }}
        alt="an img tag"
      />
      <p>And this uses a div with backgroundImage</p>
      <div
        style={{
          backgroundImage: `url("../assets/images/sandwich.jpg")`,
          backgroundSize: "cover",
          backgroundPosition: "center",
          width: "200px",
          height: "200px",
          border: "1px solid black"
        }}
      ></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Test;
```

WRITE YOUR CODE LIKE THIS:

```
import img1 from "../assets/images/sandwich.jpg";

const Test = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>This uses the img tag</p>
      <img
        src={img1}
        style={{ width: "100px", height: "100px" }}
        alt="an img tag"
      />
      <p>And this uses a div with backgroundImage</p>
      <div
        style={{
          backgroundImage: `url(${img1})`,
          backgroundSize: "cover",
          backgroundPosition: "center",
          width: "200px",
          height: "200px",
          border: "1px solid black"
        }}
      ></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Test;
```

The difference is that you don't write your backgroundImage property like this:

```
backgroundImage: `url("../assets/images/sandwich.jpg")`,
```

You write it like this:

```
backgroundImage: `url(${img1})`,
```

Comment: but I can't use the `import` method because the filename will be taken from a database. I only added the `img1` because it works for the `img` tag.

Comment: May I kindly ask what database are you using?

Comment: I want to use mysql to store the filenames

Comment: I am sorry. I have never worked with mysql. I thought the question was about an image not displaying on a div. Sorry for also not understanding that you don't want to use the import method

Comment: no problem. thank you for taking the time to respond to my question. btw I've found the solution and posted it as an answer if anyone is interested.

Answer (score 0):

> as **img1** will contain a react generated link for your image in assets folder you should use img1 as a link in url of the background image as

```js
{
// ...
backgroundImage: `url(${img1})`,
// ...
```

Answer (score -1):

after watching this [video](https://youtu.be/guIeDEND3F4) I tried using `require` like this and it works wonderfully. I hope this can help other people who are stuck with this problem.

```
const Test = () => {
  const img2 = require('../assets/images/sandwich.jpg');
  // or if this doesn't work, try adding .default after require
  // so it will be require('../assets/images/sandwich.jpg').default
  ..
  <div style={{
    backgroundImage:`url(${img2})`
  ..
```